# React Datasheet Grid - Logging Copy/Paste Values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing a React app to show Excel data in web interface. I'm using [**Equify/react-datasheet-grid**](https://github.com/Equify/react-datasheet-grid) component for it. For watching changes after copy/paste, I want to see differences in console. I added `copyValue` and `pasteValue` props to `albumId` column to see what happens but both of functions only return:

```
({
      rowData
    }) => rowData
```

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { DataSheetGrid, textColumn } from 'react-datasheet-grid';
import 'react-datasheet-grid/dist/index.css'

function index() {
    const valueCopy = (value) => {
      console.log(value);
    }

    const valuePaste = (value) => {
      console.log(value);
    }
  
    const columns = [
      textColumn({ title: 'Album ID', key: 'albumId', copyValue: valueCopy(({ rowData }) => rowData), pasteValue: valueCopy(({ rowData }) => rowData)}),
      textColumn({ title: 'ID', key: 'id' }),
      textColumn({ title: 'Title', key: 'title' }),
      textColumn({ title: 'URL', key: 'url' }),
      textColumn({ title: 'Thumbnail URL', key: 'thumbnailUrl' }),
    ];

  
    return (
        <DataSheetGrid
            data={data}
            onChange={setData}
            columns={columns}
            height={850}
        />
    )
  }
  
  export default index;
```

How can I see all copy/paste changes in whole table? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solved!

OK, here is my implementation:

```
const valueCopy = (column, data) => {
      console.log("Copied value:",data.rowData[column]);
      return data.rowData[column];
    }

    const valuePaste = (column, data) => {
      console.log("Pasted value:",column, data);
      data.rowData[column] = data.value;
      return data.rowData;
    }
  
    const columns = [
      textColumn({ title: 'Album ID', key: 'albumId', copyValue: (data)=>valueCopy("albumId", data),  pasteValue: (data)=>valuePaste("albumId", data)}),
      textColumn({ title: 'ID', key: 'id', copyValue: (data)=>valueCopy("id", data), pasteValue: (data)=>valuePaste("id", data)}),
      textColumn({ title: 'Title', key: 'title', copyValue: (data)=>valueCopy("title", data), pasteValue: (data)=>valuePaste("title", data) }),
      textColumn({ title: 'URL', key: 'url', copyValue: (data)=>valueCopy("url", data), pasteValue: (data)=>valuePaste("url", data) }),
      textColumn({ title: 'Thumbnail URL', key: 'thumbnailUrl', copyValue: (data)=>valueCopy("thumbnailUrl", data), pasteValue: (data)=>valuePaste("thumbnailUrl", data) })
    ];
```

And here is my log after copy/paste:

```
index.js:13 Copied value: officia delectus consequatur vero aut veniam explicabo molestias
index.js:13 Copied value: aut porro officiis laborum odit ea laudantium corporis
index.js:13 Copied value: qui eius qui autem sed
index.js:18 Pasted value: url {rowData: {…}, value: "officia delectus consequatur vero aut veniam explicabo molestias"}
index.js:18 Pasted value: url {rowData: {…}, value: "aut porro officiis laborum odit ea laudantium corporis"}
index.js:18 Pasted value: url {rowData: {…}, value: "qui eius qui autem sed"}
```